# How can I integrate OpenCV C++ code with python code in Anaconda environment on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, anaconda, wrapper

I need to use the [ArUco C++ library](https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/26) for a part of my project where my main programming language is Python. I could not install [python wrapper for ArUco](https://github.com/fehlfarbe/python-aruco) on my system in Anaconda environment. It just throws errors. So I thought I could install and write a code in OpenCV in C++ and can transfer the result to my main Python code. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with cffi http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, you can also make a C dll and use it in python with the built in ctypes library https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you going to detect ArUco makers? If so, you may try OpenCV 3.2 with `contrib` modules which include a [ArUco marker detection (aruco module)](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d9/d6d/tutorial_table_of_content_aruco.html) module. This [Aruco in opencv](http://www.philipzucker.com/aruco-in-opencv/) webpage has python code example.

You can get `OpenCV3.2` with `contrib` prebuilt binary from this [site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv) for Python 3.5 or 3.6 on Windows 32-bit or 64-bit platforms. It can be installed to Anaconda by `pip install {filename}.whl` as `conda install` doesn't support whl file.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that with OpenCV 3.1 and Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04. I get this error: `AttributeError: module 'cv2.aruco' has no attribute 'getPredefinedDictionary'`

Comment: One more question: Can I install OpenCV 3.2 in an existing env with OpenCV3.1?

Comment: It would be better to uninstall OpenCV 3.1 before installing 3.2 to avoid any issue. If you are installing 3.1 through conda,it won't take time and is striaght forward.

Comment: I do have OpenCV3.1 and also have cv2.aruco ( it seems ). I thought of installing OpenCV3.2 due that error in the previous comment.

Comment: I haven't tested cv2.aruco yet. Might test it if have time tomorrow. By the way, what's the conda command you used to install OpenCV 3.2?

Comment: I used `conda install -c menpo opencv3=3.2.0
`

Comment: Did you see `getPredefinedDictionary(...)
      getPredefinedDictionary(dict) -> retval` on the help output when you run `help(cv2.aruco)`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It is working now. I created a new `env` with Python 3.5 and OpenCV 3.2. `cv2.aruco` is working now.

Comment: Good that the problem fixed. It looks the `opencv_contrib` (v3.1) and your python environment caused the disconnection. Create a new virtual environment in Anaconda for OpenCV 3.2 is a clear cut approach.

Comment: @user5311361 would you give me a vote up if your question is answered?

Comment: @user5311361 Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Earlier, I did not have enough reputations to do this otherwise I would have done it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use boost python to easily write python functions in C++!

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html

```
// non-compiling example:
namespace py = boost::python;
// you have access to all python builtins using the py:: namespace
py::list create_list(py::dict dictionary, py::tuple tuple);
```

In order to nicely pass OpenCV data to/from python, there is numpy support:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/ndarray.html

```
// non-compiling example:
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;
np::ndarray modify_image(np::ndarray image);
```

I am not sure whether opencv data can directly be used somehow... Probably yes.